# i am facing a windows case problem with npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, node-modules

I am facing this error when I am trying to start a react project:

> Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\Júlio\desktop\deletealso\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\Júlio\Desktop\deletealso\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

I think the error is due to the paths not matching and it seems to be a Windows problem. Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when deploying react app and it keeps sayings << Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377211/error-when-deploying-react-app-and-it-keeps-sayings-plugin-react-was-confli)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, extremely annoying ! if you open package.json with VSCode and save it, it will fix this, but you literally have to save it every time you make a change which is not very practical... i will be waiting for a solution to this as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, first, uninstall the eslint extension from VScode if you have installed it.
Then run `npm uninstall -g eslint`,
then run `npm install -g eslint` to reinstall eslint extension in VScode.
Then close your terminal & VSCode and reopen them and try npm start again.
It works for me.