# I'm getting a error in react Plugin eslint-config-react-app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, error-handling, next.js

i'm facing a problem in react app whenever i save the document.
The error is

> Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app

i tried to solve this error with lot of methods but it's not going.

my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377211/error-when-deploying-react-app-and-it-keeps-sayings-plugin-react-was-confli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you, and i got tired doing Ctrl + S on package.json, which is a one of the solutions. Another way to solve that is your path you have MERN (all uppercase) and the path that the error show to you have mern (all lowercase) so you can rename that folder to desktop and it will solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).