# Error when redeploying my react app with nodemon it keeps sayings "Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react"-app »

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm starting a new React app and if I start it with `npm start` I have no problem but if I start it with `nodemon` I start having `Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app »`  each time I redeploy my application :

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vks0k.png)

[Error's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3mUf.png)

I have read this topic : *[Error when deploying react app and it keeps sayings << Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377211/error-when-deploying-react-app-and-it-keeps-sayings-plugin-react-was-confli)* and each time I save my package.json the error disappears and each time I change my code it comes back.

I tried :

- removing my node_modules folder and `npm install`
- downgrading eslint-config-react-app to the version 6

I am still very new to nodeJS development, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodemon is for node.js it wouldn't make sense to run nodemon with React. If you're trying to use a backend service with node.js then you would run nodemon on your server file (e.g. `nodemon server.js` or `nodemon index.js`). But these should be seperate from your React app folder. For example you could have the following:

```
|Root
   |backend
      -server.js
   |client
      |src
         -app.js
```

or like this:

```
|Root
   -server.js
   |client
      |src
         -app.js
```

You would then run two seperate calls. While in the `server.js` folder you would run `nodemon server.js`. Then in the client folder you would run `npm start` but make sure you are running them on different tabs of your command-line interface. They should be running simultaneously.

Comment: Oh yes Thank you,! I actualy got confused with my back end, I'm still learning I guess.