# Issue on install packages in React

Tags: reactjs

I use react "17.0.1" and trying to install new packages " react-idle-timer " it gives me the following error:
[image]

Comment: Seems like  react-idle-timer is broken. Did you try npm audit?

Comment: No, let me try that.. thanks

Comment: @kanuos! I did the npm audit then run npm audit fix .. but still not work

Comment: solved my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596908/could-not-resolve-dependency-error-peer-react16-8-0-17-0-0-from-materia

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596908/could-not-resolve-dependency-error-peer-react16-8-0-17-0-0-from-materia