# Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created a react project using

`npm init -y`

`npm install react react-dom`

then i try to install material UI

`npm install @material-ui/core`

It gets the error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-sidebar@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /.npm/_logs/2023-10-17T20_20_42_394Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

I didnt understand what does this error message is trying to say. using `--force`  I was able to install material UI but I didnt understand what is the problem here.

This solution is also seems to fix the issue but I think I shouldnt get an error at the first place I shouldnt set the legacy peer deps.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72597065/21970496

https://v4.mui.com/getting-started/installation/
here it says that `react >= 16.8.0 and react-dom >= 16.8.0 are peer dependencies`  My react version is 18 but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm i
```