# I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

I'm trying to run build but it's not working. It shows
Failed to compile.

> Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Projects\Assignment\login-signup\client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Projects\Assignment\login-signup\Client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

[image]

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/70391240

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "homepage":"." in the package.json file to run build in Your project