# Getting error with Visual Studio React/ ASP.NET launch

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a ASP.NET Core project with a react frontend in Visual Studio 2022. I've been following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022.
Every time I launch the project, I get this error:

```
Starting the development server...
Failed to compile.

[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\cooke\source\repos\GameApp\GameApp\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\cooke\source\repos\GameApp\gameapp\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\cooke\source\repos\GameApp\GameApp\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\cooke\source\repos\GameApp\gameapp\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377211/error-when-deploying-react-app-and-it-keeps-sayings-plugin-react-was-confli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating Node.js version.