# declaring a constant and calling in through return function

Tags: reactjs

I have done my React app setup but I found an error in the compilation:

```
[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\i trader\documents\react\myblog\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\i trader\Documents\react\myblog\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\i trader\documents\react\myblog\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\i trader\Documents\react\myblog\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
```

How can I resolve this error?

I am just declaring a constant and starting NPM but it shows an error highlighted above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict in the casing of your pathing for the documents directory: C:\Users\i trader\documents\react... vs. C:\Users\i trader\Documents\react...

You can resolve the error by fixing the casing of your Documents directory so that it matches the node modules path. You can also cd to the directory matching the casing of the windows directory and run npm start.

See this post for most details:

[Error when deploying react app and it keeps sayings << Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377211/error-when-deploying-react-app-and-it-keeps-sayings-plugin-react-was-confli)