# Getting this Error somtimes when I run 'npm start' Command for my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, eslint

Failed to compile.

> [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\dell\desktop\text-to-speech\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\dell\Desktop\text-to-speech\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
> ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\dell\desktop\text-to-speech\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\dell\Desktop\text-to-speech\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

webpack compiled with 1 error

My package.json looks like this :

```
{
    "name": "text-to-speech",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

How to fix this error? I don't want this error to show me up when I run npm start.

I want terminal to show me like this :

```
You can now view ReactProjectName in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000        
  On Your Network:  http://193.158.42.103:3000   

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when deploying react app and it keeps sayings << Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377211/error-when-deploying-react-app-and-it-keeps-sayings-plugin-react-was-confli)

Comment: You have a "Desktop" and a "desktop" that appear to be interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had similar error in eslint plugin. Hope following the steps below solves your problem:

1. remove any douplicate plugin-react from the file .eslintrc from your project root folder.
2. reinstall your eslint plugin (eslint-plugin-react). Removei before installing it.
3. restart your npm start command.