# Getting Errors in Building or Deploying React App

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a problem in deploying or building a React app. I always getting this error,
`Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\MIS-NOGS\documents\github\ronskie69\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\MIS-NOGS\Documents\GitHub\ronskie69\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".`

I would like to know why this happened and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is specific to Windows, and in the past, React would have still executed the application despite this discrepancy. However, it appears that this is no longer the case.

To resolve this, You need to located the folder and opened it with Visual Studio Code, ensuring that the path precisely matches what is stored in the node modules.

same issue with fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70391240/14836684